# Jinja2 unpacking list into method args

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a jinja macro with a check inside it, the macro receives a set of permissions in a list passed to it, the check will ensure that the user has the correct permissions to render the macro. For this to work with the check method, I need to be able to unpack the list as positional arguments. This doesn't seem to be possible in Jinja2, it seems to not understand the syntax. That or I haven't come across a way yet.

**Macro**

```
{% macro edit_field(text, link, permissions=['hello', 'goodbye']) -%}
  {% if user.has_permissions(*permissions) %}
    Do Something
  {% endif %} 
{%- endmacro %}
```

**Check method**

```
def user_has_permissions(*permissions)
user.has_permissions('hello', 'goodbye')
```

Comment: Do you have to do this in the jinja template? Might be easier to create the boolean server side and then pass it to jinja.

Comment: Please include the error message you're getting.